# Particles won't collide with object?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I have a particle system in 2.8 that emits metaballs, and Ive added Collision to the object I want to collide with. Settings on the collision have friction at 1.

Ive followed tutorials, however my metaballs pass right thru the collision object -

Can metaballs not collide? Whats wrong here?

[image]

Comment: test this using spheres or something.  If that produces the same result, it's not the metaballs.  Then try replacing the collision object with a simple mesh.

Comment: @RBlong2us no, even spheres dont collide with a simple plane.

Comment: how about changing the collision object?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blenderartists.org/t/collision-with-metaballs/1154033/2

Comment: I tried using a particle system with metaballs, and the collided just fine.  do you have any other modifiers on your collision object?

Comment: on the particles object, in the particles panel, in physics, and under deflection, do you have a collection selected under collision selected?(if you do and your colliding object isn't under that collection, it won't work)